# Why does the date-range of the table on the left side of a LEFT JOIN not limit the bytes processed in the same way as a where clause?

Tags: google-bigquery, left-join, where-clause, operator-precedence, order-of-execution

I'm trying to understand why the date-range restriction imposed by the first table in a Left Join does not limit the Bytes Processed in the same way as adding a WHERE clause with the same restriction does.

Query 1: Bytes Processed = 3.9 GB

```
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.calendar_halfhour` as cal
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.big_table` as t
ON cal.tstamp = t.tstamp
```

Query 2: Bytes Processed 1.07 GB

```
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.calendar_halfhour` as cal
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * 
  FROM `project.dataset.big_table` 
  WHERE tstamp BETWEEN "2022-09-01 00:00:00 UTC" AND "2022-11-24 00:00:00 UTC"
  ) as t
ON cal.tstamp = t.tstamp
```

In the above queries `project.dataset.calendar_halfhour` is a table of halfhourly incrementing timestamps created using the below query. In other words it already contains the date range restriction that is used in Query 2. Although it returns the same result, there is a significant difference between the bytes processed for Query 1 and Query 2 and I am not sure why.

```
SELECT tstamp 
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY("2022-09-01 00:00:00 UTC",
                                     "2022-11-24 00:00:00 UTC",
                                     INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)) AS tstamp
```

Clarification:

- The big_table is partitioned by tstamp (by DAY), not sure if that will make a difference
- The Left hand table: project.dataset.calendar_halfhour is much smaller than the right hand table
- I realise that my query might not be best practice, I am not concerned by that - I created it solely to try and understand the processing happening in the background a bit better in order to better optimise queries in future.

My assumption was that in a LEFT JOIN it will first look at the small table on the left, and then fetch only the rows required of the big table on the right (as specified by the tstamp field that it must join on). Therefore I assumed that adding a WHERE clause providing the same tstamp limitations shouldn't change the bytes processed. But it does and I am not sure why.

Comment: Is your table partitioned or clustered by the field `tstamp`?

Comment: Yes the big table is partitioned by tstamp by day as far as I am aware. Does this make a difference to the order of execution? Have edited question to add a bit more clarity.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

In both queries, tstamp has the same size. But in query 2, you are filtering out the amount of data that is involved in the join, therefore the amount of total processed data is smaller compared to query 1.

You can quickly check this out by measuring the size of big_table compared to the subquery.

In other words, the size of tstamp is not a hard limit for data processing, since bigquery still needs to join it with all values on the other side of the join.

Adding the large set first will be more performant, according to the docs:

*it is still recommended to order your joined tables appropriately. As a best practice, place the table with the largest number of rows first, followed by the table with the fewest rows, and then place the remaining tables by decreasing size.*

*When you have a large table as the left side of the JOIN and a small one on the right side of the JOIN, a broadcast join is created. A broadcast join sends all the data in the smaller table to each slot that processes the larger table. It is advisable to perform the broadcast join first.*

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns

Comment: I would add that BQ recommends putting your biggest table on the LHS of a join.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, you said "for each row on the left, the engine needs to find matches on the right side" therefore if the left table is already limited to the specified date range I would have thought that adding the Where clause to the right table (specifying the same date range) is redundant. Why is it looking at tstamps in the big_table that is not in the left table?

Comment: Remember that the bytes processed indicator is not the addition of both tables but all the addition of all the data exchanged in different execution phases between all the slots.

By having a smaller left-side dataset, the total processed data will be smaller compared to a join where the left-side dataset is larger.

Comment: I am fairly new to SQL so I might be misunderstanding you, but in both queries the left side table is project.dataset.calendar_halfhour which is substantially smaller than the table on the right hand side. The Where clause in the second query adds no additional restriction to the big_table that the Left Join doesn't also do.

Comment: For each record on the left side, the engine will find any matches on the right side.

By having a smaller right-side dataset, the work to do so is also smaller. Therefore, the bytes processed will be smaller compared to a larger dataset on the right side.